# Como selecionar um campo e digitar nele com selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando selecionar o campo input porem não estou conseguindo.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\Desktop\Teste.py", line 7, in <module>
    elem.clear()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 95, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="arroz" id="feijao">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://sisbibliotec.com.br/a.html")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('arroz')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('username')
```

Comment: Qual versão do python você está utilizando? Eu executei seu código aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Python 3.6

Comment: Tanto no python 2.7 quanto no 3.6 esta dando esse error. Estou utilizando o Windows 10 aqui, não sei se faz diferencia.

Comment: Pode ser a versão do Driver também, aconteceu isso com um amigo meu do nada o driver começou dar pau, tenta pegar o mais atual e testar novamente, eu estou usando o driver mais recente.

Comment: Mas se fosse o driver não ia abrir o navegador, e o navegador esta abrindo e redirecionando para o site certo, o problema é que ele não consegue selecionar o campo.

Comment: O problema que acontecia com meu amigo também era na hora de manipular as informações, o driver vai continuar abrindo normal eu me refiro a alguma mudança que fez ele parar de funcionar direito.

Comment: Baixei novamente foi de primeira.
Responda para eu colocar como certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser a versão do driver que você está utilizando, algumas funções podem parar de funcionar entre a transição de uma versão para outra.

Você sempre pode pegar a ultima versão do driver do Chrome aqui:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started